# Compute sqrt(5) in Z_11 with Fermat's little theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

I am trying to solve this.

If I am correct, applying Fermat's little theorem here gives:

$\sqrt{5}^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$

$\sqrt{5}^{10} = 5^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$

$5^{2} \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$ 
$5^{3} \equiv 5*5^2  \equiv 3*5 \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$ 
$5^{5} \equiv 5^2*5^3  \equiv 3*4 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$

but I have no idea how to use the fact that $11 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

and also, since $Z_{11}^*$ = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} is not the $\sqrt(5)$ in $Z_{11}^*$ the same as in $Z$ ?

Comment: What is meant by $Z_{11}^*$?

Comment: @MarkFischler Cardinality

Comment: I think he means the multiplicative group inside $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've thrashed around a bit, but you've managed to close in on a solution.

Since $5^5 \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ as you verified, also $5^6 \equiv 5 \bmod 11$.

So:

> $5^3$ is a square root of $5$ modulo $11$.

However this discrete square root of $5$ mod $11$ is not "the same" as a square root in the integers $\mathbb{Z}$.  Not sure how you meant that last remark.

This is a particular case where, given a quadratic residue $n$ mod $p$, when prime $p$ is congruent to $3$ mod $4$, the modular square roots of $n$ mod $p$ can be explicitly computed or expressed as:

$$ \pm n^{\frac{p+1}{4}}  $$

This may well have been discussed in your text or other study materials.  In any case it is mentioned as the first step of the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

Comment: Yes but this does ot use the hint and barely uses Fermat's little theorem.  You could easily say $1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2\equiv 16\equiv5$ bingo,  but this is clearly not the point of the problem.

Comment: @MarkFischler: I believe the significance of $11 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ lies in the "easy" case of extracting a modular square root.  Namely when prime $p = 4k+3$, then the square roots of $n$ can be given explicitly as $\pm n^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$.  This is often discussed in connection with Fermat's Little Thm. and/or taking modular square roots, but I'm guessing about what material prompted this exercise.

Comment: +1 for your insight that the material was probably teaching the $4k+3$ fact   along with FLT.

Answer (score 2):

Some supplementary background to hardmath's answer.

- Note that $\sqrt{5}$ does not exist in $\mathbb{Z}$.
- The answer is "obviously" $4$. Indeed, $4^2 = 16 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$. This would be entirely a sufficient answer. For toy questions like that, the answer is usually not very big, so you can just try the first few numbers which are $5 \pmod{11}$ and see if they're square.
- There is [an efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm) for this kind of problem.